# How can I get Deja-Dup to use my "Skydrive" account instead of Ubuntu One?

Tags: deja-dup

Wow can I set Deja-Dup to use my "SkyDrive" as the backup, since I have so much more storage?

Any ideas or successful attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do that check [Here.](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/01/automatically-backup-to-skydrive-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/)

Its for 11.10, but I tried it, and it works on 12.04

Comment: ok thanks, good to know that it works! I have seen this page already but I was concerned with going through "SME Storage", just since I don't know them. But thank you!! I will give it a shot!

Comment: We can't get the information over here?

Comment: @Braiam What do you mean?  The link? I just checked, and it works.

Comment: I mean copying the information here.

Comment: I still don't understand what is it that you trying to to.  What I did is just follow the steps in the link, and it worked.  Can you explain?